# when run locust --master and client locust --master-host,locust can not run api stress,why?

Tags: python, centos, locust

### qs

when run locust --master and client locust --master-host,

locust can not run api stress,why?

### env

server: locust -f locustfile.py --master (centos)

client: locust -f locustfile.py --worker --master-host 10.200.6.1 (mac)

### status

visit webUI,worker show 1 worker,but start test,

it will stop immediately after three seconds,

rps and result still show None.

### cmd log

error log : lewis-test/INFO/locust.main: Starting Locust 1.2.3

passlog :

lewis-test/INFO/locust.main: Starting Locust 1.2.3

lewis-test/INFO/locust.runners: Spawning 100
users at the rate 100 users/s (0 users already running)...

lewis-test/INFO/locust.runners: All users spawned: MyUser: 100 (0 already running

Comment: Can you add your locustfile to the question? And the complete logs.

Comment: fix ths.........

Answer (score 0):

it work
diferent locust version,ths